# ReactでScroll Revealを実装したい時の変数の定義の仕方について

Tags: javascript, react-jsx

ReactでコンポーネントにScroll Revealを実装したいのですがその際に npmでscroll revealをinstall後、実装したいコンポーネントPost.jsに `import scroll reveal` を定義しその中でアニメーションさせたいclassnameに対して以下を定義しましたがimportしたscroll revealが反応せずmodule not foundとエラーとなります。

**例:**

Post.js内

```
ScrollReveal().reveal('当てたいクラス');
```

*対処としては別コンポーネントを作成してそこにscroll reveal用のjsを作成してPost.jsにてそれをimportするも同じエラーになります。
またPost.js内でconst = Postと定義してscroll revealの設定を書くとparsing error(2重変数)となってしまいます。

Scroll revealを実装するにはどのような定義あるいは実装の仕方がいいかお分かりになる方がいましたらどなたかご教授よろしくお願い致します。